# Independence of Circular Contour Radius - Part 1

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

([link to part 2 of question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311523/264))

**Problem:**

Let $P$ and $Q$ be smooth functions on $D$ satisfying $\partial P / \partial y = \partial Q / \partial x$. Let $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ be two closed paths in $D$ such that the straight line segment from $\gamma_0 (t)$ to $\gamma_1 (t)$ lies in $D$ for every parameter value of $t$. Then $\int_{\gamma_0} P$d$x + Q$d$y = \int_{\gamma_1} P$d$x + Q$d$y$. Use this to demonstrate that, by using Green's theorem, $\oint_{|z|=r}P$d$x + Q$d$y$ is independent of the radius $r$, for $a<r<b$.

An attested solution$^1$ to the problem can be found on the Net, which states that—in the words of Gamelin$^2$—provided we let $D$ be a domain, and we let $\gamma_0 (t)$ and $\gamma_1 (t)$, $a \le t \le b$, be two closed paths in $D$, and if we suppose that $\gamma_0$ can be continuously deformed to $\gamma_1$, in the sense that for $0 \le s \le 1$ there are closed paths $\gamma_s (t)$, $a \le t \le b$, such that $\gamma_s (t)$ depends continuously on $s$ and $t$ for $0 \le s \le 1$, $a \le t \le b$, then since

$\hspace{2in} \int_{\gamma_0} P$d$x + Q$d$y = \int_{\gamma_1} P$d$x + Q$d$y$

for any closed differential $P$d$x + Q$d$y$ on $D$ we can use straight lines to deform $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma_1$ having defined $\gamma_s (t) = s \gamma_1 (t) + (1-s) \gamma_0 (t)$, $0 \le s \le 1$, $a_1 \le t \le b_1$, for which the above theorem applies. The solution goes on to say that "by parameterizing the circles $|z| = r_0$ and $|z| = r_1$ by $\gamma_0 (t) = r_0 e^{2 \pi it}$, $\gamma_1 (t) = r_1 e^{2 \pi it}$, $0 \le t \le 1$ [the] straight lines segments joining $\gamma_0 (t)$ to $\gamma_1 (t)$ are radical [and] are in the annulus."

[1] (p.015) http://tinyurl.com/ad2e62c
[2] (p.082) http://tinyurl.com/anmmcq8

[*] (p.222) http://tinyurl.com/bxhb866
[*] (p.320) http://tinyurl.com/ayhsnko

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", "Show", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Trancot, please do not revert to the original title because it makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption on the force field $K:=(P,Q)$ guarantees that $K$ is *locally exact*. By Green's theorem this means that for any simply connected$^1$ subdomain $\Omega\subset D$ the integral $\int_\gamma(P\>dx+Q\>dy)$ along any closed curve $\gamma\subset\Omega$ is zero. Write $P\>dx+Q\>dy=:\omega$.

Assume $t'<t''$ are nearby values of the parameter $t$. Then there is a simply connected subdomain $\Omega\subset D$ containing the arcs $$\alpha_0:\ t\mapsto\gamma_0(t),\quad \alpha_1:t\mapsto \gamma_1(t)\qquad (t'\leq t\leq t'')$$ as well as the segments $\sigma'$ and $\sigma''$  connecting $\gamma_0(t')$ with $\gamma_1(t')$ and $\gamma_0(t'')$ with $\gamma_1(t'')$. As $\lambda:=\alpha_0+\sigma''-\alpha_1-\sigma'$ is a closed curve in $\Omega$ it follows that
$$\int_{\alpha_0}\omega -\int_{\alpha_1}\omega=\int_{\sigma'}\omega-\int_{\sigma''}\omega\ .\tag{1}$$
Now divide the common parameter interval $[0,1]$ into  sufficiently   small pieces $[t_{k-1},t_k]$ $\ (1\leq k\leq N)$, such that to each piece the equality $(1)$ can be applied. Summing the $N$ resulting equations up, the right sides telescope to $0$, so that we obtain
$$\int_{\gamma_0}\omega - \int_{\gamma_1}\omega=0\ ,$$
as stated.

The example with the two circles is a special case of the above.

[1] http://tinyurl.com/at9zypv

Comment: When you say "force field $K := (P, Q)$," how do you mean?

Comment: Thank you, Christian Blatter.

Comment: @Trancot: Fields $(P,Q)$ that are integrated "along" lines I call force fields; when they are integrated "across" lines I call them flow fields.

Comment: OK, and when you say "locally exact" you mean "conservative," correct?

Comment: Don't you mean "multiply connected"?

Comment: @Trancot: I meant "simply connected". "Locally exact" means: Conservative in a suitable neighborhood of the considered point. The field $\nabla\arg$ is locally exact in the punctured plane, since locally you can define real-valued polar angles.