# Independence of Circular Contour Radius - Part 2

Tags: complex-analysis

([link to part 1 of question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/308814/264))

> Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are smooth functions on the annulus $\{a<|z|<b\}$ that satisfy $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$. Show directly using Green's theorem that $\oint_{|z|=r}P\,dx+Q\,dy$ is independent of the radius $r$, for $a<r<b$.
>
> Consider the diagram below:
>
> [image]

So, I'm reexamining an old homework problem, and I'm wondering how showing that if

$\hspace{2in}$ $\oint_{|z| = r_1} P$d$x + Q$d$y = \oint_{|z| = r_2} P$d$x + Q$d$y$,

then independence is shown. **How should I think of independence here**? So, if I show that $\oint_{r_1} (\star) = \oint_{r_2} (\star)$, then $r_1$ and $r_2$ both produce the same result, and thus the contour integration does not depend on $r$, correct?

---

**multiply connected region**

A region
which is not simply connected; a region
in which there exists some simple closed
curve, which cannot be shrunk continuously
to a point without leaving the region. An mconnected
region is one whose complement
has m simply connected components.

---

**simply connected region**

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Green's theorem, for multiply-connected domain $G$, with boundary $\partial{G},$
$$\oint\limits_{\partial{G^+}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy}=\iint\limits_{G}{\left(\dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}-\dfrac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}\right)\,dx\,dy}.$$
Applying Green's theorem to  the annulus $A= \{z\colon \;\;\; r_1 < |z| < r_2,\;\; a < r_1 < r_2 < b \} $ with boundary $\partial{A}=C_{r_1}\cup C_{r_2}$, where $ C_{r_i}=\{|z|=r_i \} \;\;(i=1,2) $, we have
$$\oint\limits_{{{C_{r_1}^{+}\cup C_{r_2}^{-}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy}=\iint\limits_{A}{\left(\dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}-\dfrac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}\right)\,dx\,dy}=0,$$
therefore,
$$\oint\limits_{{{C_{r_1}^{+}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy}=-\oint\limits_{{{ C_{r_2}^{-}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy} =\oint\limits_{{{ C_{r_2}^{+}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy} $$

Comment: The orientation does not matter?

Comment: How do the last two integrals on the last line become equal?

Comment: Oh, I see. $C_{r_2}^{-} \ne C_{r_2}^{+}$

Comment: Orientation of the contour is chosen so that interior of the contour lies to the left when moving along the contour, so positive orientation in the answer is opposite to one in your drawing.     
At the last line $-\oint\limits_{{{ C_{r_2}^{-}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy} =\oint\limits_{{{ C_{r_2}^{+}}}}{P\,dx+Q\,dy},$ because the contour integral changes its sign when you change the contour orientation.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem states, use Green's Theorem:

$$\oint_{|z|=r}P\,dx+Q\,dy = \int_D dx \, dy \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right )$$

where $D$ is the disk enclosed by the circle $|z|=r$.  Now, the relation $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ only holds in the annulus $r \in (a,b)$, so inside the disk, but outside the annulus, the equality no longer holds.  We deal with this by noting that

$$\int_D dx \, dy \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right ) = \int_{|z|<a} dx \, dy \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right ) + \int_{a<|z|<r} dx \, dy \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right )$$

Note that the second integral vanishes, and the first integral does not depend on $r$.  Therefore, the LHS is independent of $r$, and the line integral from which it was based is independent of $r$.

Note also that if $P$ and $Q$ are smooth in the annulus, then they are smooth inside the entire disk by analytic continuation.

Comment: For any onlookers curious about what Green's Theorem is, check out this [link](http://tinyurl.com/a3jq3o6).

Comment: @Trancot: I'm not quite sure I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: Check my most recent edit. Also, check your integral notation. Is it correct?